# Can't seem to click on a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm extremely new at coding, but I'm really fond of it and I'm trying to learn some basic things right now. So for a school project I have to make a website using HTML and CSS.

I've been working on a smooth scrolling thing and a side nav bar (which admittedly I've copied from w3schools.com). But I tried adding a link to the sidebar, which will go to another page of mine. This however doesn't seem to work, as when I try to click the link it won't go anywhere. I've tried making a separate link on the main page but that doesn't seem to work either. As I already said I'm new at this so it could be a stupid problem but please take a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>orginele titel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=site.css>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=site.html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=foto.html>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "6") {
      event.preventDefault();   
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
   
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } 
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#section1 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}
#section2 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 4, 4);
}
 </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
     
     <h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>

      <div class="main" id="section1">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>hi</p>
        <a href="biografie.html">biografie</a>
          
       
        <a href="#section2">hoe cool zijn vissen
        </a>
        </div>
      
      <div class="main" id="section2">
       
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <a href="#section1">To go back to the top</a>
       </div>
       <div class="sidenav">
        <a href="foto.html">bee</a>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a 
      </div>
      
      
         
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the css

```
h1{
    color:grey;
    text-align: center;
}


p{
    text-align: center;
   
}

#p1{
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(146, 5, 5);
    font-size: 50px;
}


body{
    background-color: rgb(14, 7, 7);
}

.sectie1 {
    color: grey;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  
  a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  p{
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-weight: bold;
  }



.sidenav {   
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .main {
    margin-left: 160px; 
    font-size: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }
```

Also, feel free to critique my code as much as you want. That way I can learn from my mistakes!

Comment: Why you are using "this.hash" in your event handler, instead use "this.href" to get the value and you that?

Comment: hi, as i said in the question I copied that part from w3schools, so i dont really know what that's all about.

Comment: I would advice don't copy paste the code, instead learn the concept and then try to implement. Start small

Comment: probably the best thing to do. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is the script that you have used in the  section. I suggest removing that and styling with plain HTML and CSS.

You're missing the .html from the end in the href attribute.

```
 <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="foto.html">bee</a>
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
    <a href="clients.html">Clients</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a
  </div>
```

Link to a new HTML page that you're going to create in the same folder.

Using external links:

```
<a>href="https://www.whateverpage.com/">Visit Whateverpage</a>
```